# How to use a different font for a particular element in a Beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, fonts

I'm trying to customise a Beamer template and while it's easy to change the font for the entire presentation using `\setmonofont{}` and `\setsansfont{}`, I can't figure out how I can change the font of a single element. For instance I'd like to use different fonts for `title` and `author` in the title page. `\setbeamerfont{}` seems to allow modifying properties of a font in each section but not the font itself?

**UPDATE**
So I just discovered `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` commands. If I wrap the section I want into a group then I can apply a new `setmonofont{}` inside the group and achieve what I want. However, this looks like a hack and I prefer if all the font changes were made in the font drx file.

Comment: It’s a bit late to post a full answer, but `\setbeamerfont` supports `family=`, which lets you change the font family.

Comment: Isn't that limited to internal fonts? Is there a way to use external fonts (with XeLaTeX and fontspec) similar to `setmonofont{}` and `\setsansfont{}` ?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with `\setbeamerfont{...}{family=}`, or `\setbeamerfont{...}{family*=}` for legacy NFSS font families.

Here is an example that declares a `\newfontfamily` with the modern toolchain and `unicode-math`.  It requires LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

```
\documentclass[noamssymb,
               professionalfonts,
               xcolor={HTML, svgnames, Svgnames}
              ]{beamer} % Loads several other packages, including amsthm and geometry.
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}

\geometry{paperwidth = 10cm} % Appropriate width for a MWE on TeX.SX.

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale = MatchLowercase }
\newfontfamily\avantgarde{TeX Gyre Adventor}[Ligatures=Common]
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{family=\avantgarde}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{There Is No Largest Prime Number}
  \framesubtitle{The proof uses \textit{reductio ad absurdum}.}

  \begin{theorem}
    There is no largest prime number.
  \end{theorem}
  \begin{proof}
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item Suppose $p$ were the largest prime number.
      \item Let $q$ be the product of the first $p$ numbers.
      \item Then $q+1$ is not divisible by any of them.
      \item But $q + 1$ is greater than $1$, thus divisible by some prime
                number not in the first $p$ numbers.\qedhere
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{proof}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Font sample with Adventor]

In a real document, you would want to set up a few extra `\setmathfont[range=...]` commands to tweak things like the math letters and QED symbol.  I didn’t do that here, to keep this example minimal, so the font selection will look pretty strange.

And here is an example compatible with PDFLaTeX:

```
\documentclass[xcolor={HTML, svgnames, Svgnames}
              ]{beamer} % Loads several other packages, including amsthm and geometry.
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % The default since 2018.

\geometry{paperwidth = 10cm} % Appropriate width for a MWE on TeX.SX.

\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{family*=qag} % TeX Gyre Adventor

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{There Is No Largest Prime Number}
  \framesubtitle{The proof uses \textit{reductio ad absurdum}.}

  \begin{theorem}
    There is no largest prime number.
  \end{theorem}
  \begin{proof}
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item Suppose $p$ were the largest prime number.
      \item Let $q$ be the product of the first $p$ numbers.
      \item Then $q+1$ is not divisible by any of them.
      \item But $q + 1$ is greater than $1$, thus divisible by some prime
                number not in the first $p$ numbers.\qedhere
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{proof}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Type1 font sample]

In this case, you would need to pass the NFSS family name to `family*=`.  [The documentation of the font](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tex-gyre/adventor/README-TeX-Gyre-Adventor.txt/view) tells us that the filenames are `qagr`, `qagb`, `qagri` and `qagbi`, so the common prefix of the font family is `qag`.  (This made sense at the time.  Back when the lowest common denominator of a file system supported only eight-letter filenames, and every variant font face needed its own filename, family names needed to be cryptic.  GUST chose the prefix `q` for its TeX Gyre fonts because it was nearly unused, and Adventor is a clone of Avant Garde Gothic.)

Some legacy font packages define an NFSS family name that might work with `family=`.  You would need to check the documentation.

You can also select a font family within an element, e.g. `\frametitle{\avantgarde There is no Largest Prime Number}`.