# What is this font (beamer)?

Tags: beamer, fonts

[image]

I know this might be hard but does anyone know this font?

Comment: if you have the pdf your pdf viewer or the pdffonts utility will tell you the fonts used.

Comment: Seem be Avant Gard font: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/474051/how-to-use-a-different-font-for-a-particular-element-in-a-beamer-presentation

Comment: It looks like `Helveitca`, or `Optima` or `Univers`

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture)

Comment: @MadyYuvi It is very definitely not either of those fonts! It is a different style to the typefaces you mentioned. (Helvetica and Univers are neo-grotesques, Optima is a humanist, while the one here is some kind of geometric typeface.)